# Datatables individual column filter with multiple checkbox selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

i found this code in https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html, to make some filters in my datatable. but now i want to select multiple values with checkbox selection, how can i do it?

```
initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns([0, 1, 6]).every(function () {
                var column = this;
                //var select = $('<select><option value="">' + $(this.header()).html() + '</option></select>')
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: How so? You want a checkbox for each entry in the column?

Comment: I want i checkbox for the dropdown that appears in select filters per each column like in the example of datatables @iamdlm

Comment: Why not add a column with a checkbox per row?

Comment: @iamdlm I Want to make a filter like excel.. like 2 values from "that" column

Comment: That will require a lot of work to achieve, you'll probably have to append and html table to the footer containing a checkbox for each row, handle events for hide, show, filter, etc. A workaround, although it looks awful is using the [<select> multiple Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp).